# Wiring receptacle

Tags: wiring, receptacle

Take a look at attached picture of one of my wall outlet. I am removing switch from this outlet to make it always hot, and use that switch to control recessed lights.

As you can see, 2 of the neutral push in connectors already occupied by 2 neutral wires ( one from power source and other going to next outlet). I need to connect 3rd neutral wire from switch( recessed lights). Can I use side screw to connect 3rd neutral wire ?

[image: outlet]

Comment: yes, but you could also remove the neutrals and connect them together with a pig-tail (added white wire) which than connects to the receptacle.